# Returning value from persisted Groovy code without using java.io.File

Tags: java, groovy

In my end product, I provide the ability to extend the application code at runtime using small Groovy scripts that are edited via a form and whose code are persisted in the SQL database.

The scheme that these "custom code" snippets follow is generally returning a value based on input parameters. For example, during the invoicing of a service, the rating system might use a published schedule of predetermined rates, or values defined in a contract in the application, through custom groovy code, if an "overridden" value is returned, then it should be used.

In the logic that would determine the "override" value of the rate, I've incorporated something like these groovy code snippets that return a value, or if they return null, then the default value is used. E.g.

```
class GroovyRunner {

    static final GroovyClassLoader classLoader = new GroovyClassLoader()
    static final String GROOVY_CODE = MyDatabase().loadCustomCode()
    static final String GROOVY_CLASS = MyDatabase().loadCustomClassName()
    static final String TEMPDIR = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")

    double getOverrideRate(Object inParameters) {
        def file = new File(TEMPDIR+GROOVY_CLASS+".groovy")

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))
        bw.write(GROOVY_CODE)
        bw.close()

        Class gvy = classLoader.parseClass(file)
        GroovyObject obj = (GroovyObject) gvy.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()
        return Double.valueOf(obj.invokeMethod("getRate",inParameters)
    }
}
```

And then, in the user-created custom groovy code:

```
 class RateInterceptor {
    def getRate(Object inParameters) {
        def businessEntity = (SomeClass) inParameters

        return businessEntity.getDiscount() == .5 ? .5 : null
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that these "custom code" bits in GROOVY_CODE above, are pulled from a database during runtime, and contain an intricate groovy class. Since this method will be called numerous times in succession, it is impractical to create a new File object each time it is run.

Whether I use GroovyScriptEngine, or the GroovyClassLoader, these both involve the need of a java.io.File object. This makes the code execute extremely slowly, as the File will have to be created after the custom groovy code is retrieved from the database. Is there any way to run groovy code that can return a value without creating a temporary file to execute it?

Comment: use GroovyClassLoader.parseClass​(String text) http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader.html#parseClass(java.lang.String)

Comment: Running this through the use cases now, but appears to be the answer to my problem. If you post as an answer with explanation, I would be happy to mark as the accepted answer.

Comment: My only issue is that GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(String xxx) caches an instance of the script, even if the same script is being executed, according to [the docs](https://groovy-lang.org/integrating.html) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straight solution for your case would be using `GroovyClassLoader.parseClass​(String text)`

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader.html#parseClass(java.lang.String)

The class caching should not be a problem because you are creating each time a new `GroovyClassLoader`

---

However think about using groovy scripts instead of classes

your rate interceptor code could be like this:

```
def businessEntity = (SomeClass) context
return businessEntity.getDiscount() == .5 ? .5 : null
```

or even like this:

```
context.getDiscount() == .5 ? .5 : null
```

in script you could declare functions, inner classes, etc

so, if you need the following script will work also:

```
class RateInterceptor {
    def getRate(SomeClass businessEntity) {
        return businessEntity.getDiscount() == .5 ? .5 : null
    }
}

return new RateInterceptor().getRate(context)
```

The java code to execute those kind of scripts:

```
import groovy.lang.*;
...

GroovyShell gs = new GroovyShell();
Script script = gs.parse(GROOVY_CODE);
// bind variables
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.setVariable("context", inParams);
script.setBinding(binding);
// run script
Object ret = script.run();
```

---

Note that parsing of groovy code (class or script) is a heavy operation. And if you need to speedup your code think about caching of parsed class into some in-memory cache or even into a map

```
Map<String, Class<groovy.lang.Script>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Straight-forward would be also:

```
GroovyShell groovyShell = new GroovyShell()

Closure groovy = { String name, String code ->
  String script = "{ Map params -> $code }"
  groovyShell.evaluate( script, name ) as Closure
}

def closure = groovy( 'SomeName', 'params.someVal.toFloat() * 2' )
def res = closure someVal:21

assert 42.0f == res
```

Comment: Can GroovyShell.evaluate() evaluate an entire complex class with import statements and private fields? From the Apache documentation it appears as though they only recommend evaluate() method for simple expressions. My end user will be defining the logic to return whatever value, not necessarily just a primitive data type.

Comment: Yes, it can. It can evaluate complete classes with package name, imports and the rest,  that a normal groovy class would havw